# Get city code for the city which get from current location eg., New York, NY

Tags: iphone, reverse-geocoding, currentlocation

In my application, I m getting City name from current location using `MKReverseGeocoder`

I also getting Country code but I want is City code too.

For exmaple If I get New York city than i want to get NY. So i can show **New York, NY**

can any one help please how can i get or any link ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

NY isn't a "city code", it's the abbreviation for the State of New York. A US state is an `administrativeArea` as far as `MKPlacemark`/`CLPlacemark` is concerned. The geocoder only provides one canonical city name -- if you want an abbreviation for it, you'll have to look somewhere else.

Also note that on iOS 5.0 and newer, you should be using `CLGeocoder`, not the deprecated `MKReverseGeocoder`.

Comment: okay thanks for reply but i am not clear from above that can i get abbreviation for cityname or not ?

Comment: Cities have canonical names, but not necessarily canonical abbreviations. Apple's geocoder (and most other geocoders) only provide the former.